# How to name sublists with character strings from inside a function?

Tags: r, list, lapply

I am new new to R lists have trouble naming sublists. I want a good and clear sublist naming convention for future ease of access to the data embedded in a sublist. The image below explains shows what I would like to output when running my `createTmp()` function. The code posted at the bottom generated the left-side of the below image, and the right-side shows what I am trying to achieve with character-string named sublists. Basically, I would like to replace the `[[...]]` numeric indexing with the correct character string identifying the sublist. How would this be done?

Also, I'm open to any improvement or simplification of the below `createTmp()` code!! I've been stumbling through this. I am trying to stick with `lapply()` as much as possible in lieu of for-loops.

[image]

Code:

```
seriesVector <- function() {c("DF_One", "DF_Two")}

dfList <- 
  list(
    Elements = 
      list(
        DF_One = c("Boy", "Cat"),
        DF_Two = c("Rat", "Bat")
      ),
    Shares = 
      list(
        DF_One = c(0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6),
        DF_Two = c(0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4)
      )
  )

createTmp <- function(nbr_rows) {
  series <- seriesVector()
  allocate <- list(Allocate = as.list(setNames(rep(0, length(series)), series)))
  
  allocate$Allocate <- lapply(series, function(series_name) {
    df_values <- dfList$Shares[[series_name]]
    df_values
  })
  
  merged_list <- c(allocate)
  names(merged_list) <- c(names(allocate))
  return(merged_list)
}

createTmp(3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100%. what are you trying to achieve in the end but IMHO there is no need to use `lapply`. Instead you could do:

```r
createTmp <- function(nbr_rows) {
  series <- seriesVector()

  list(Allocate = dfList$Shares[names(dfList$Shares) %in% series])
}

createTmp(3)
#> $Allocate
#> $Allocate$DF_One
#> [1] 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6
#> 
#> $Allocate$DF_Two
#> [1] 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4
```

Comment: I figured there was a slick, concise solution out there. I need to keep practicing with Lists.

Comment: I'm studying your "element matching" solution and its an eye-opener for me, it's better than my usual use of `apply` functions and for-loops for reading through vectors, lists, dataframes, etc.  Do you think it is also faster when working with large data? I just posted a related question to try to figure out it's broader use, at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76447020/how-to-use-element-matching-in-place-of-apply-and-for-loop-functions-when-readin