# How to use element matching in place of apply and for-loop functions when reading through dataframes and lists in R?

Tags: r, list, apply, lapply, matching

I was just introduced to "element matching" in post [How to name sublists with character strings from inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76445543/how-to-name-sublists-with-character-strings-from-inside-a-function) which appears to be much better than my usual method of reading through lists/dataframes using for-loops and `apply()` functions. Is there a way to replace the two `lapply()` functions in the example code below with element matching (`[x %in% y]`)? I'm fiddling with it but haven't gotten it to work yet. My single example of "element matching" in the code below is highlighted with `# ELEMENT MATCHING`.

My `createBucket()` function cobbles together three lists but in the `lapply()` part of the code creates sublists for all the elements found in the `dfList` list under the $Elements name (and which are also represented in the `seriesVector()` function) and creates little 3-column dataframes/matrices for each, with the number of rows set by the input parameter `nbr_rows`. It works fine but I wonder if there's a better or more efficient way to do this especially using "element matching".

The image at the bottom of this post shows the (correct and desired) output of running the `createBucket()` function.

Code:

```
balVector <- c(1000,1000,1000)
flowVector <- c(6,5,4)
seriesVector <- function() {c("DF_One", "DF_Two")}
dfList <- 
  list(
    Elements = 
      list(
        DF_One = c("Boy", "Cat"),
        DF_Two = c("Rat", "Bat")
      ),
    Shares = 
      list(
        DF_One = c(0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6),
        DF_Two = c(0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4)
      ),
    Rate = 
      list(
        DF_One = 0.10,
        DF_Two = 0.20
      )
  )

createBucket <- function(nbr_rows) {
  total <- list(
    Total = list(balVector = balVector,flowVector = flowVector)
  )
  
  series <- seriesVector()
  
  allocate <- list(Allocate = dfList$Shares[names(dfList$Shares) %in% series]) # ELEMENT MATCHING
  
  merged_list <- c(total, allocate, lapply(series, function(series_name) {
    setNames(
      lapply(dfList$Elements[[series_name]], function(element) {
        df <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nbr_rows, 3))
        colnames(df) <- c('Inflow', 'Due', 'Outflow')
        df
      }),
      dfList$Elements[[series_name]]
    )
  }))
  
  names(merged_list) <- c(names(total), names(allocate), series)
  return(merged_list)
}

createBucket(3)
```

[image]